# Does Mathematica simplify calculation when encounter zero?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, arithmetic

e.g.
when Mathematica Calculating `f[x0]=A[x0] B[x0]`,
where A[x] & B[x] could be some complicated high dimensional function.

Will Mathematica outcome 0 directly when `A[x0]=0`, instead of still calculating `B[x0]`?

Comment: As far as i understand mma in its processes of internal calculations, will generally follow the typical (), / z, +- rules and then see if 0 or a 1/0 is somewhere in the calculation as it goes through it process, should A[x] === 0 and that’s immediately given, and depending on the internal function rules, it will likely report 0

Comment: Correction: `f[x0_?NumericQ] := Module[{Ax0 = A[x0]}, If[Ax0 == 0, 0, Ax0*B[x0]]];`

Comment: A few reasons why `0` does not shortcut evaluations are: `0 × Infinity` evaluates to `Indeterminate`, `0 × Undefined` evaluates to `Undefined`, `0 × 1.0` evaluates to `0.` (`Real` rather than `Integer`), `0 × IdentityMatrix[2]` evaluates to `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` (matrix rather than `Integer`), etc.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @Vladimir Reshetnikov Thanks! Now I understand it in detail.

Comment: @morbo Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick experiment shows it does not stop, but it will evaluates all expressions on RHS, even if one is zero.

```
f1[x_] := 0
f2[x_] := (Do[PrimeQ[n], {n, 1, 10000000}]; 1)
f1[x]*f2[x]
```

It still called `f2[x]`

Even doing this

```
f1[x_] := 0
f2[x_] := (Do[PrimeQ[n], {n, 1, 10000000}]; 1)
Evaluate[f1[x]]*f2[x]
```

had no effect. It is still slow, because it evaluated `f2[x]`

Even this

```
f2[x_] := (Do[PrimeQ[n], {n, 1, 10000000}]; 1)
0*f2[x]
```

had no effect. It is still slow, because it evaluated `f2[x]`

Comment: `Times` does not have a `HoldAll` attribute, so it HAS to evaluate everything. Functions that are capable of short-circuit evaluation such as `Or` and `And` have hold attributes for this reason.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  Sure. I understand. The OP is using `Times` as the example they give.

Comment: succinct and clear!